# Build failed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

> Process 'command 'C:\sec\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: provide more info or this question will be closed.

Comment: You need to give more information. What were you trying to do when you got this error? What is your code? Also you should edit your question title to give more information.

Comment: Try to run flutter doctor on your command window/terminal. It will display the errors you are facing during the gradle build. If it's your first build in flutter, then you must haven't set it up correctly. Use flutter doctor and fix the errors and try again.